# Represent a list varible in an Azure DevOps pipeline, for use with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to have a list of items that I can iterate in PowerShell scripts in several stages of a release pipeline.

How can I represent a pipeline variable with multiple values, like a list? For instance, this variable could contain a list of languages.

What would be the syntax to access this pipeline variable from PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the syntax to pass a yaml list from an Azure DevOps pipeline parameter to an inline PowerShell script. The key is to use the convertToJson yaml method  to convert the yaml object to json. Then converting that json into a PowerShell object with ConvertFrom-Json.

**Parameters**

```
    parameters:
    - name: environmentVariableList
      type: object
      default:
        - key: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
          value: DV
        - key: Variable2
          value: Value2
```

**Inline Script:**

```
InlineScript: |
  $environmentVariableList = '${{ convertToJson(parameters.environmentVariableList) }}' | ConvertFrom-Json
  foreach($i in $environmentVariableList)
  {
    Write-Host "Setting environment variable [$($i.key)] to [$($i.value)]"
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($i.key, $i.value, "Machine")
  }
```

Comment: Great! In the "Pipeline variables" section I press "Add" and then I am asked to add "Name" and "Value". If I add a variable ```Languages```, how can I specify multiple values?Would it be like a semicolon-separated list like ```en;fr;de``` ?

Comment: This is an example of pipeline parameters used in a yaml pipeline. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema

Comment: OK! Parameters seems very useful. I think I really need to find out where the YAML editor for release pipelines can be found...

Comment: You would need to start with a yaml pipeline rather than a ui pipeline

Comment: This worked for me! Except i didnt need the surrounding ‘[]’ brackets and could drop them. Also i needed to use .name instead of .key

Comment: @Warren  
The '[]' brackets in write-host is part of my logging style. It allows me to identify a missing variable in the logs if the variable resolves blank. It's easier to spot brackets than a double space. Will work with and without the brackets.